# soundness issue with integer/bv mixed benchmarks?

Tags: z3

I've the following SMT-Lib2 script:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun s0 () Int)
(declare-fun table0 (Int) (_ BitVec 8))
(assert (= (table0 0) #x00))
(assert
   (let ((s3 (ite (or (< s0 0) (<= 1 s0)) #x01 (table0 s0))))
   (let ((s5 (ite (bvuge s3 #x02) #b1 #b0)))
   (= s5 #b1))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

With Z3 v3.2 running on the Mac, I get:

```
sat
(model 
  ;; universe for (_ BitVec 8):
  ;;   bv!val!2 bv!val!3 bv!val!0 bv!val!1 
  ;; -----------
  ;; definitions for universe elements:
  (declare-fun bv!val!2 () (_ BitVec 8))
  (declare-fun bv!val!3 () (_ BitVec 8))
  (declare-fun bv!val!0 () (_ BitVec 8))
  (declare-fun bv!val!1 () (_ BitVec 8))
  ;; cardinality constraint:
  (forall ((x (_ BitVec 8)))
          (and (= x bv!val!2) (= x bv!val!3) (= x bv!val!0) (= x bv!val!1)))
  ;; -----------
  (define-fun s0 () Int
    (- 1))
  (define-fun table0 ((x!1 Int)) (_ BitVec 8)
    (ite (= x!1 0) bv!val!0
    (ite (= x!1 (- 1)) bv!val!3
      bv!val!0)))
)
```

Which states that s0 = -1 is a model. However, with s0 = -1, we have s3 = 1 and s5 = #b0, which makes the assertion false. In fact, I'm quite sure the benchmark as stated is unsatisfiable.

One thing I noticed in the Z3 output is the quantified formula it gives for the cardinality constraint. It says:

```
  ;; cardinality constraint:
  (forall ((x (_ BitVec 8)))
          (and (= x bv!val!2) (= x bv!val!3) (= x bv!val!0) (= x bv!val!1)))
```

The assertion is a conjunction, which sounds rather weird; shouldn't that be a disjunction? I'm not sure if this is the root-cause of the problem, but it sure sounds fishy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in Z3.
First, you are correct, there is a typo in the model printer. It should be a "or" instead of an "and". The second problem is that Z3 did not install the bit-vector theory and treated `(_ BitVec 8)` as a uninterpreted sort. This was a bug in the preprocessor that is used to decide in which logic the problem is in. You can workaround this bug by adding the following command in the beginning of the file:

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
```

These bugs have been fixed, and the fix will be available in the next release.